# Play Audio from Ftp using Xamarin MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, xamarin, ftp

I am trying to play an audio file from my local ftp Server like this:

```
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.SetAudioStreamType(Android.Media.Stream.Music);
        mp.SetDataSource("ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/AC_DC_Black_Ice.mp3");
        mp.Prepare();
        mp.Start();
```

I am able to access the file via browser, however I get an error on the following statement

```
mp.Prepare()
```

> "Java.IO.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1"

What am i missing here?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to work.  You should download the file to local storage first, then play it.

Comment: I don't know anything about Xamarin (MediaPlayer), but maybe it is possible via an UDP connection, like Youtube does.

Comment: @Jason I tried downloading the file, however when i try to save it i end up with `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. I tried to write the file into "/storage/emulated/0/Music/".

I granted my application the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission.

Comment: well, then you should solve **that** problem